# Rock, Papers and Scissors in Python

Tags: python

(I am new to python, please don't judge the quality of the code right now.)

So, I am making a program which let's you play rock, papers and scissors with the code. This is my code:

```
import random

name = str(input("Enter your name:\n"))

choices = ["rock", "papers", "scissors"]

print(f"Hi {name}, choose between rock, papers and scissors")

while True:
    user_choice = str(input('> '))
    user_choice.lower()

    if user_choice not in choices:
        print("ERROR")

    computer_choice = random.choice(choices)
    print(f"Computer chooses: {computer_choice}")

    if user_choice == "rock":
        if computer_choice == "papers":
            print("Computer wins!")
        elif computer_choice == "scissors":
            print(f"{name} wins!")

    if user_choice == "papers":
        if computer_choice == "scissors":
            print("Computer wins!")
        if computer_choice == "rock":
            print(f"{name} wins!")

    if user_choice == "scissors":
        if computer_choice == "rock":
            print("Computer wins!")
        elif computer_choice == "papers":
            print(f"{name} wins!")

    if user_choice == computer_choice:
        print("Tie!")
```

But, like when I run the code, it is working out really good. However, the problem is that if the user does not enter the correct spelling, the output looks really messed up. Like this:

```
Enter your name:
_____
Hi _____, choose between rock, papers and scissors
> asdf
ERROR
Computer chooses: rock
```

I do not want the last line, the one which says "Computer chooses: rock". Please someone suggest how do I go about this.

Thanks in advance

(EDIT: Also, if you can suggest how I can include a point system in this, which calculates how many times the computer wins, the user wins and how many times the match was a tie, the effort would be really appreciated.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `continue` to force the user to enter a valid choice:

```
while True:
    user_choice = str(input('> '))
    user_choice = user_choice.lower()

    if user_choice not in choices:
        print(f"You chose {user_choice}, please choose rock, paper, or scissors")
        continue

    [...]
```

Comment: Please can you also suggest some code for the points system.

Comment: That's an entirely separate question.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask this in another question, please suggest your code over there.
Please.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your error problem has already been solved : )
But for the tie and score counter I have prepared the following code-

```
import random

name = str(input("Enter your name:\n"))

choices = ["rock", "papers", "scissors"]

print(f"Hi {name}, choose between rock, papers and scissors")

Cwin = 0

Userwin = 0

Tie = 0

while True:
    user_choice = str(input('> '))
    user_choice.lower()

    if user_choice not in choices:
        print("ERROR")

    computer_choice = random.choice(choices)
    print(f"Computer chooses: {computer_choice}")

    if user_choice == "rock":
        if computer_choice == "papers":
            print("Computer wins!")
            Cwin = Cwin + 1
            print(int(Cwin) , "Computer victories so far")
        elif computer_choice == "scissors":
            print(f"{name} wins!")
            Userwin = Userwin + 1
            print(int(Userwin) , "User victories so far")

    if user_choice == "papers":
        if computer_choice == "scissors":
            print("Computer wins!")
            Cwin = Cwin + 1
            print(int(Cwin) , "Computer victories so far")
        elif computer_choice == "rock":
            print(f"{name} wins!")
            Userwin = Userwin + 1
            print(int(Userwin) , "User victories so far")

    if user_choice == "scissors":
        if computer_choice == "rock":
            print("Computer wins!")
            Cwin = Cwin + 1
            print(int(Cwin) , "Computer victories so far")
        elif computer_choice == "papers":
            print(f"{name} wins!")
            Userwin = Userwin + 1
            print(int(Userwin) , "User victories so far")

    if user_choice == computer_choice:
        print("Tie!")
        Tie = Tie + 1
        print(int(Tie) , "Ties so far")
```

Look here the screenshot of it working properly-
[image]

Comment: Hey @Hydraulic, really sorry to say that this code is not working. Please get in touch with me, even I have made some necessary changes.

Comment: What changes did u make?

Comment: how can i send screenshot?? XD

Comment: @coding123 u can look in the edited answer above :)

Comment: Yes, got it!! Thank you!

Comment: Check out my GitHub repository I made on this over here: https://github.com/bachansmit/rock-papers-scissors-with-python

Comment: I think it was because the variable names were in capitals.

Comment: @coding123 I am so glad i helped u : )

Answer (score 0):

Just add computer choose inside else:

```
import random

name = str(input("Enter your name:\n"))

choices = ["rock", "papers", "scissors"]

print(f"Hi {name}, choose between rock, papers and scissors")

while True:
    user_choice = str(input('> '))
    user_choice.lower()

    if user_choice not in choices:
        print("ERROR")
    else:
        computer_choice = random.choice(choices)
        print(f"Computer chooses: {computer_choice}")

    if user_choice == "rock":
        if computer_choice == "papers":
            print("Computer wins!")
        elif computer_choice == "scissors":
            print(f"{name} wins!")

    if user_choice == "papers":
        if computer_choice == "scissors":
            print("Computer wins!")
        if computer_choice == "rock":
            print(f"{name} wins!")

    if user_choice == "scissors":
        if computer_choice == "rock":
            print("Computer wins!")
        elif computer_choice == "papers":
            print(f"{name} wins!")

    if user_choice == computer_choice:
        print("Tie!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible implementation:

```py
import random

name = str(input("Enter your name: "))

choices = ["rock", "scissors", "paper"]

print(f"Hi {name}, choose between rock, paper and scissors")

while True:
    user_choice = None
    while user_choice not in choices:
        user_choice = str(input('> '))
        user_choice.lower()

    computer_choice = random.choice(choices)
    print(f"Computer chooses: {computer_choice}")

    if user_choice == computer_choice:
        print("Tie!")
    elif choices[(choices.index(user_choice) + 1) % len(choices)] == computer_choice:
        print(f"{name} wins!")
    else:
        print(f"Computer wins!")
```

Some insights:

- You can accomplish the comparing mechanism with a rounded list, and not explicit comparison.
- Do a while loop for the user input until it is correct.

Comment: If it helps you, you can accept the answer and upvote, but, I agree with @chepner, this is a different question.